# A boat is traveling at 30 knots/hour at 30 degrees E of N. What are the components of the velocity vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Is it something kind of like 30cos(30) and 30sin(60) ?

Comment: Yes, it is something kind of like that.  Have you drawn a picture?  You should be able to get pretty good numbers.  Label the angles from your vector to each axis.  If you draw from the head of the vector to the axes, the 30 is the hypotenuse of two right triangles.

Comment: The units in the title are wrong: knots/hour is a unit of acceleration, not speed. The boat is travelling at a speed of 30 knots: a knot is one nautical mile per hour.

Comment: Can you post a picture on here, I tried to do it on my phone but I couldn't find anything here that will let me upload a pic ?

Comment: Ya my prof just put that for an exam review question, maybe it's just so we can learn the concept I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is the vector you described, then it has length 30 and forms a right triangle on the $x$-axis with base $v_x$ and height $v_y$.  Let $\theta$ be the angle between $v_x$ and $v$ (so in this case, since you specified the direction was 30° east of north, the angle with which we are concerned is $\theta=90°-30°=60°$).  The velocity components you seek are the triangle sides $v_x$ and $v_y$.  From trigonometry, $$\cos{\theta}=\frac{v_x}{v}$$ and $$\sin{\theta}=\frac{v_y}{v}$$ which means $v_x=v\cos{\theta}$ and $v_y=v\sin{\theta}$.

Comment: Wait so is X = 30cos(60) and Y= 30sin(30)   based on what you are saying?

Comment: You have $v_x$ correct but the angle in $v_y$ is also 60. When I do these problems, I always take a triangle with base along the $x$-axis. So $\theta$ is the same in both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Your latter statement is correct for the velocity component in the $Y$ direction. However, your component for the $X$ direction will be $30 \sin(30 ^\circ)$. This is because taking the component in the x direction requires you to find the opposite side when you are given an angle and a hypotenuse.